# Set Ubuntu Server 14.04 to go into suspend-hybrid when idle

Tags: server, suspend, pm-utils

I have a headless server running Ubuntu Server Edition 14.04.

I have tested pm-suspend-hybrid and it works. I am able to manually put the server into suspend-hybrid through command line.

I am also successfully able to resume the server through WoL from another machine.

What I would like to do is get the server to automatically go into suspend-hybrid when not in use for at least 30 mins.

*By **use** I mean:*

- *remote machines are accessing NFS shares on the server over the
  network*
- *my TV is accessing DLNA content over the network*

If it is too complicated to determine when a machine is idle, alternatively I would like to set the server to go into suspend-hybrid from 01:00 AM every day.

Is there any tutorial or step by step process I can use to get this working?

Comment: Run man crontab and look at the syntax there to put your command to run at 1am.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What I would to is put the DLNA and NFS log level to `info`, then parse the logs and see whether there was no activity for 30 minutes and then use `pm-suspend-hybrid.` (I would run the script every 5 minutes using `cron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to what @Daniel said:

The following will make the computer `pm-suspend-hybrid` every day at 1 A.M.:

`0 1 * * * pm-suspend-hybrid >/dev/null 2>&1`

Add this line to your crontab (You can access your crontab by running `sudo crontab -e`)

Comment: Thanks very much this worked. I had to amend the command slightly to get it working by pointing it to the location of pm-suspend-hybrid.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help :)